# how do you import an image into python without external software?

Tags: image, python-2.7, import

This is for primary school students who only have access to the main software, not Pygame or Tkinkter or any of that. This is a group of people named LPPJJAS sending this message and we woud like a code return.

Comment: Tkinter is documented as a standard Python library module. [See the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html). But if for some reason it is not acceptable, Python Imaging Library (PIL) is probably the easiest external library to set up What platform are you using?

Comment: I am using windows, with python 2.7.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter is documented as a standard Python library module. See the official documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html). Tkinter is primarily a user interface widget toolkit rather than than an image processing library anyway, although one can display images in it.

But if for some reason Tkinter is not acceptable, the Pillow fork of the Python Imaging  Library is probably the simplest option for an image processing library.

It's not a part of the base language but is maintained at the Python foundation's package index.

Executable installers for Pillow, for Windows and Python 2.7, as well as Python eggs and Python wheels (for Windows and other OS's), and setup instructions, can be found at [the Pillow 2.9.0 official site](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.9.0). Choose the one appropriate to your version of Windows (32 or 64 bit) for Python 2.7.

There is also some documentation on the library itself at that site.